# Error in List saved in user settings: The strings does not save

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have an List saved in my user settings, it should save several strings, but when I check its value (by Settings.Default.FileList.Count) it displays that the value is 0, when I save a string, it displays the number of strings saved, but when I Change of form or I restart the app, it's again 0.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: make sure you are looking into same list (user settings) in which you had saved string earlier. - Single and common object should be there across all forms

Comment: Did you save your strings with Properties.Settings.Default.Save();?